# Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 windowing randomly crashes, begins logging errors

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, shutdown, crash, reboot

A couple of months ago, I had been using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad T570 for a year or so, when my laptop windowing crashed for the first time. I restarted it, and it went back to normal for a week or so before doing it again. Over the next couple of weeks, it did this a half dozen times. For the next two weeks after that, it was completely stable and didn't freeze once. Last week, it started crashing again.

The symptoms are:

- Side bar disappears
- Components of the top bar disappear
- Top bar itself disappears
- Lose ability to switch windows
- Application windows stop responding or rendering
- May shutdown windowing completely and go to a black screen.

I ran Lenovo's builtin hardware diagnostics, and everything comes back fine. So I decided to try upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 to see if that would solve the issue. I did **not** do a clean install, but upgraded instead.

In the week since the upgrade, 18.04 has crashed twice. The behavior is very similar to the 16.04 crashes, though the error messages and speed of the crash seem somewhat different.

The error messages from this last crash, which are repeated continuously until I hard shutdown are:

- `EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p2) ext3_find_entry:1436: inode#[NUMBER]: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0`
- `systemd-journald[268]: Failed to write entry ([NUMBER] items [NUMBER] bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system`

Other than that, I don't have other concrete data points to help nail down what's going on. But here are a few other thoughts that might be useful:

- As far as I can tell, nothing I'm doing triggers this response. I spend most of my time in Chrome, Pycharm, and the command line. I can be doing anything in any of those (or other applications) when this happens.
- My system is pretty stock. I don't do a lot of tinkering with system settings, and hadn't messed with anything in a while when the first crash happened.
- The reboot after a crash isn't always successful. Sometimes it'll get stuck on the Lenovo logo, sometimes a blank screen, sometimes Ubuntu's logo will appear for a bit before a purple blank screen.
- It *seems like* waiting longer between shutdown and reboot increases the likelihood that the restart will be successful.

Any thoughts on what might be going on would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

### Update 1

In repsonse to @heynnema suggestion:

The `SMART Data & Tests` button is grayed out and cannot be clicked (on any device/partition). I did: `sudo apt install smartmontools`, after which the `SMART Data & Tests` button stayed gray. In an attempt to get some relevant information, I then ran `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1p2`. It doesn't produce any information including "sector", but the output is below:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-29-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLW256HEHP-000L7
Serial Number:                      S35ENX0J599958
Firmware Version:                   4L7QCXB7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            168,824,696,832 [168 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Thu Feb 28 18:47:38 2019 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL *Other*
Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     69 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     72 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.60W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     5.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1500
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2200    6000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        28 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    3,685,965 [1.88 TB]
Data Units Written:                 8,000,875 [4.09 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 54,265,691
Host Write Commands:                86,676,003
Controller Busy Time:               399
Power Cycles:                       1,823
Power On Hours:                     646
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   93
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      267
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               28 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               29 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0        267     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  1        266     0  0x0016  0x4016  0x004            0     1     -
  2        265     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  3        264     0  0x0016  0x4016  0x004            0     1     -
  4        263     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  5        262     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  6        261     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  7        260     0  0x0026  0x4016  0x004            0     1     -
  8        259     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
  9        258     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
 10        257     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
 11        256     0  0x0016  0x4016  0x004            0     1     -
 12        255     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
 13        254     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
 14        253     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
 15        252     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
... (48 entries not shown)
```

I also looked at the `smartctl` man page, but it wasn't obvious which flag(s) might give more information about sectors.

### Update 2 (03/05/19)

Even though I've had several crashes in the last few days, `ls -al /var/crash` doesn't show any crashes in that time frame:

```
jessime@jessime-t570:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 59072
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Mar  5 11:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Jan 31  2018 ..
-rw-r-----  1 jessime  whoopsie 37795148 Mar  1 10:39 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 jessime  whoopsie        0 Mar  1 10:39 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Mar  1 10:40 _usr_bin_gedit.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 jessime  whoopsie 22683033 Feb 27 19:04 _usr_bin_pulseaudio.1000.crash
```

Comment: "Read-only file system" usually indicates a hardware or filesystem fault: Look up how to run a SMART test on your HDD, and look up how to run fsck from a LiveUSB to test your filesystem.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Have you installed a Windows driver to read/write to ext2/3/4 file systems? Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu file system? See my partial answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets check your Ubuntu file system first...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

**Then lets check the SMART Data...**

- open the `Disks` application
- select `SMART Data & Tests` from the hamburger icon
- review the data, looking for parameters with "sector" in the name
- take a screenshot and edit it into your question
- run the SMART Tests

**Update #2:**

**I think that you have a SSD firmware problem.** See [this update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds119265), but double-check that I've got the right one for your machine. Both Lenovo and Samsung have updater tools, so do a little homework. Do a backup FIRST, and then do the update. You'll need to run the updater in Windows.

Comment: RE your comment: I'm not dual booting, but the computer did originally come with Windows installed, if that matters.

From a Live USB, running `sudo fdisk -l` gives me, among other lines: `/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 466876415 465825792 222.1G Linux filesystem`.

Then, running `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2` produces:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: ...
Pass 2: ...
Pass 3: ...
Pass 4: ...
Pass 5: ...
/dev/nvme0n1p2: 961722/14557184 files (0.7% non-contiguous), 36475019/58228224 blocks
```

I've trimmed output of the lines for char. limits.

Comment: @JessimeKirk please do Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Done! (Kind of.)

Comment: @JessimeKirk hum, not much information to go on. Good job on installing smartmontools. Lets look at syslog... `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: grep gives me 21 lines of output, each of which are one of two things. 14 seem to come from inserting the Live USB: `/var/log/syslog.1:Feb 28 12:10:41 jessime-T570 kernel: [    2.720169] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk` The other 7 all happened within a second yesterday (I did have a crash yesterday, but I don't know what time): `/var/log/syslog.1:Feb 27 16:33:44 jessime-T570 ureadahead[266]: ureadahead:sda: Ignored relative path`

Comment: @JessimeKirk oh, I just realized that I may have given you an incorrect command to search for errors in syslog... in `terminal` type `df` and find the device associated with the mount at /... it may be `/dev/nvme0n1p2`... if so, the correct command would be `grep -i nvme0n1p2 /var/log/syslog*`. Edit that output into your question (not into the comments please), and I'll take a look. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @JessimeKirk also show me `sudo systemctl status ureadahead`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90416/discussion-between-jessime-kirk-and-heynnema).

Comment: @JessimeKirk I think that you have a SSD firmware problem. See https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds119265 but double-check that I've got the right one for your machine. Both Lenovo and Samsung have updater tools, so do a little homework. Do a backup FIRST, and then do the update. You'll need to run the updater in Windows. Report back.

Comment: @JessimeKirk status update please

Comment: Hey, @heynnema, busy week (I'm in the middle of writing my dissertation). Anyway, I only have Ubuntu installed on this machine. I'm not dual booting or anything. It looks like there are options to update firmware from Ubuntu (e.g. https://gist.github.com/klingtnet/22ab0b907e2d9d20f98c72c93ea5dd37), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: If this is a firmware issue, is there a risk of permanent damage if this isn't addressed immediately? I'm only going to have this laptop another couple months, and the next owner would likely install Windows and could easily install the firmware updates. The crashes aren't frequent enough for me to invest a lot of time into this at the moment (given other time constraints), if there's no risk of data loss or permanent damage.

Comment: @JessimeKirk I'd say that there IS a risk of data loss. Do lots of backups. Do the update if you can swing the time... no guarantees, but I think it would fix it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. If I have some free time and/or crashes get worse, I'll get a Windows partition installed and to the upgrade. I'll ping you again if that happens.